# Variational autoencoder: each tensor to be equal size

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I am working to train a VAE on a custom dataset (132x132, 3 classes, RGB). The model definition follows:

```
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dims):
        super(Decoder, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(latent_dims, 512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, 3*132*132)
        
    def forward(self, z):
        z = F.relu(self.linear1(z))
        z = torch.sigmoid(self.linear2(z))
        
        return z.reshape((-1, 1, 132, 132))

class VariationalEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dims):
        super(VariationalEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(3*132*132, 512)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(512, latent_dims)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(512, latent_dims)
        
        self.N = torch.distributions.Normal(0, 1)
        self.N.loc = self.N.loc.cuda()
        self.N.scale = self.N.scale.cuda()
        self.kl = 0
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        mu =  self.linear2(x)
        sigma = torch.exp(self.linear3(x))
        z = mu + sigma*self.N.sample(mu.shape)
        self.kl = (sigma**2 + mu**2 - torch.log(sigma) - 1/2).sum()
        return z

class VariationalAutoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, latent_dims):
        super(VariationalAutoencoder, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = VariationalEncoder(latent_dims)
        self.decoder = Decoder(latent_dims)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        z = self.encoder(x)
        return self.decoder(z)
```

When I train the model using the following loop:

```
def train(autoencoder, data, epochs=20):
    opt = torch.optim.Adam(autoencoder.parameters())
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for x, y in data:
            x = x.to(device) # GPU
            opt.zero_grad()
            x_hat = autoencoder(x)
            loss = ((x - x_hat)**2).sum() + autoencoder.encoder.kl
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
    return autoencoder

vae = VariationalAutoencoder(latent_dims).to(device) # GPU
vae = train(vae, train_data_loader)
```

I get this error:

```
Input In [55], in <module>
      1 vae = VariationalAutoencoder(latent_dims).to(device) # GPU
----> 2 vae = train(vae, train_data_loader)

Input In [54], in train(autoencoder, data, epochs)
      5 x = x.to(device) # GPU
      6 opt.zero_grad()
----> 7 x_hat = autoencoder(x)
      8 loss = ((x - x_hat)**2).sum() + autoencoder.encoder.kl
      9 loss.backward()

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1106 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1107 # this function, and just call forward.
   1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [53], in VariationalAutoencoder.forward(self, x)
      7 def forward(self, x):
----> 8     z = self.encoder(x)
      9     return self.decoder(z)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1106 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1107 # this function, and just call forward.
   1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

Input In [52], in VariationalEncoder.forward(self, x)
     26 def forward(self, x):
     27     x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1)
---> 28     x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
     29     mu =  self.linear2(x)
     30     sigma = torch.exp(self.linear3(x))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1110, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1106 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1107 # this function, and just call forward.
   1108 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1109         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1110     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1111 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1112 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py:103, in Linear.forward(self, input)
    102 def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 103     return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:1971, in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1969 if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight, bias):
   1970     return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight, bias), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1971 return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)

RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (128x52272 and 17424x512)
```

If I got the model right, the input of the encoder should be 132 * 132 while the output of the decoder 3 * 132 * 132.

Any suggestions to solve this?

Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to SO; please post a [mre].

Comment: Please provide the full error backtrace.